# How does IPython autoreload know a function has been changed?

Tags: python, ipython

the `%autoreload` in IPython can detect a change of a function and reload it.

How is it implemented?

Can I use python code to detect the change of a function? For example, I would like similar functionality to implement a new `memoize` context manager. If a function is changed, then the memoize cache got refreshed.

Comment: "the %autoreload in IPython can detect a change of a function" What makes you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

> `autoreload` reloads modules automatically before entering the
>   execution of code typed at the IPython prompt.

So, it reloads module before executing the code. It doesn't detect the change of a function.

Find more details on [official doc](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html#module-IPython.extensions.autoreload).

Comment: could you please provide a link to the mentioned doc? there could be more information documented that could benefit OP.

Comment: You mean it just reload everything anyway?